# understanding of rails object life cycle issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object, controller

I am new to rails.I have some confusion about about rails object life cycle.In rails we have the bellow code.

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    # GET /users
    # GET /users.json
    def index
      @users = User.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @users }
      end
    end

    # GET /users/1
    # GET /users/1.json
    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    end

    # GET /users/new
    # GET /users/new.json
    def new
      @user = User.new

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    end

    # GET /users/1/edit
    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /users
    # POST /users.json
    def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PUT /users/1
    # PUT /users/1.json
    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /users/1
    # DELETE /users/1.json
    def destroy
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to users_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end
```

then in the form we have

```
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
  </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
                          </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

my confusion is in the new action in controller i have `@user = User.new`
and again in the create `@user = User.new(params[:user]).`

then in form i have `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>` .
My question is here at the form the `@user` object actually means waht?
I mean does this `@user` is going to hit the new action or create action.

If it is going to hit the create action then how this is happening because the form is actually comes from the new action so i can't figure it out how its hitting to the create action .

i know its very simple question.But i dont know how its happening as i am new to rails.

Please help me to make me understand the object flow.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "new" action makes a new object and shows a form for editing it.  That form submits to the "create" action because the object has not been saved yet.

If you did

```
form_for @user
```

and @user was a previously-saved object, the form would submit to the update action instead.

form_for is a bit magical, like a lot of rails: it does two things:

- sets the "action" attribute of the form to point at either "/users" (for create) and "/users/:id" (for update)
- in the case of update (ie for objects that already have an id) it also adds a hidden field which triggers the update action:  this hidden field will look like this: `<input type="hidden" value="put" name="_method">`.

Have a look at form_for in your rails api.

Answer (score 0):

It's hitting `create` action because of the proper form URL. When you run `rake routes` command, you'll see that `POST /users` leads to `users#create` action - and that's the URL in the `new` form. URL is set (and form fields are generated) properly by Rails because you pass `User` instance to the form.

Comment: thanks @Marek Lipka for replying.
but that form is rendering from new action then how its hiting the create action.so then why we need to define User instance in the new action as it seems like unused .make me clear if i am wrong.

Comment: @user1463066, as I wrote, `User` instance created in `new` action is used for proper form generation with `form_for` method. It sets proper form URL and makes creating form fields convenient.